# Poincare duality for $2$d manifolds with punctured points?

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology, duality-theorems

Does the Poincare duality ($H^1=H_1$) hold for $2$-dimensional manifolds with punctured points?

Example:

Take $g=2$ surface with $2$ points punctured. It permits for $4+1=5$ linearly independent (modulo boundary) cycles. This gives $\operatorname{rank} H_1 =5$. From this, can I deduce that $\operatorname{rank} H^1=5$? (and that one can define $5$ linearly independent (up to a total derivative) $1$-forms on this surface?)

Comment: No Poincare duality doesn't work for non-closed manifolds. If you take out open disks rather than punctures, then Lefschetz duality tells you $H^1(M)\cong H_1(M,\partial M)$.

Comment: Then, by any chance, do you have an idea how to calculate the first cohomology group for the genus $g$ oriented 2-dimensional manifold with $n$ punctured points?..

Comment: Since you know $H_1$, all you need is that $H^1$ has the same rank as $H_1$ using the Universal Coefficient Theorem. Then you are done since $H^1(X)$ is torsion free for any topological space. Thus $H^1$ and $H_1$ are both free abelian groups of the same rank.